# Suppress password on saving

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel workbook/database that I have password protected when a user tries to save.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim Password As String
    Dim EnteredPassword As String
    Password = "100%Laphr0a1g"
    'EnteredPassword = InputBox("Enter password to save changes")
    'If EnteredPassword = Password Then
    EnteredPassword = InputBox("Enter password to save changes")
    If EnteredPassword <> Password Then
        Cancel = True
        MsgBox ("Password incorrect, file not saved")
    End If
End Sub
```

My problem is I want to save the workbook in another routine in Quiet mode and I don't want to enter a password.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

ChDir PathVal
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    FileNameVal _
    , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False, 
ConflictResolution:=xlLocalSessionChanges

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

What is the code to skip the `Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave` routine or code to save without entering the password?

Comment: You can use a global variable as a flag to skip the check in the event handler.

Comment: Many thanks for your help.